# How to create a slideshow which autoplays on mousedown, but stops on mouseup?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, autoplay, mousedown

I want to create a slideshow which autoplays on mousedown, and stops on mouseup. 
Als I would like it to work on a single click.

So if you click on the image, it goes to the next, if you hold your mouse button, it keeps on playing.

I tried to do something like this:

```
var mousedownID = -1;  
function mousedown(event) {
  if(mousedownID==-1)  
     mousedownID = setInterval(whilemousedown, 100 );
}

function mouseup(event) {
   if(mousedownID!=-1) {  
     clearInterval(mousedownID);
     mousedownID=-1; 
}
}

function whilemousedown() {
     timer=setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  500);
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseup);
```

It does half the job. It starts on mousedown, but doesn't stop anymore and goes on really glitchy.

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var mousedownID = -1;` to control your slides. Like, you're checking if `mousedownID == -1` then set Interval and call the function `whilemousedown` after every 100ms.

Your program is working only for mousedown but not for mouseup becuase you made a mistake in mousedown function. when you are setting Interval in if block you should have set mousedownID to some positive integer so that when mouseup function will be called it will check (mousedownID != -1). So below is the correction:

```
function mousedown(event) {
  if(mousedownID==-1){  
     mousedownID = setInterval(whilemousedown, 100 );
     mousedownID = 1;
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you in getting your program working as expected. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: and use some other variable for TIMER and then use it to clearTimeout

Comment: and I just noticed that you used `timer` variable inside `whilemousedown` function and once you set that variable you are not clearing it's time by using `clearTimeout(timer)` anywhere in the code. To stop that behavior of changing slides you need to stop `timer` as well.

Comment: Below is the link to my fiddle. I created it for you but I didn't copy your code. I have written my own code and implemented slide behavior as simple as I could. I hope it will help you learn more about the timers and language.
https://jsfiddle.net/ovd578oq/2/